# How can I pass Hudson's env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER to log4j properties and Java's System.getProperty

Tags: java, properties, hudson, log4j, environment-variables

My Hudson job calls a single XML database collection and a single log file. E.g.

- /db/project
- ${user.home}/logs/logging.log

I'd like to inject Hudson's env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER in both paths to avoid concurrent execution clashes. E.g.

- /db/project **{$EXECUTOR_NUMBER}**
- {$user.home}/logs **{$EXECUTOR_NUMBER}**/logging.log

I've found out the following:

- [Hudson site](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-1) states that I need to pass Hudson's EXECUTOR_NUMBER to Maven as part of the build goal.
- [Log4J can only use system variables](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/03/propertyvariable-reference-in.html) not environment variables (as these are a platform specific concept)

Now that I've got Hudson's EXECUTOR_NUMBER variable specified in the build goal, how can I use this as a system property for use by Log4J and Java's System.getProperties() class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass System Properties to any Java process using the -D syntax.

```
mvn clean install -DEXECUTOR_NUMBER={$EXECUTOR_NUMBER}
```

For a test class in a forked run, you will additionally have to configure the surefire plugin to pass the system property to the forked vm:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <EXECUTOR_NUMBER>${EXECUTOR_NUMBER}</EXECUTOR_NUMBER>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: That's very similar to what I've got. I'm testing this by running 'mvn clean install -DTestClassTest -DEXECUTOR_NUMBER={$EXECUTOR_NUMBER}' then logging each System.getProperty().keySet() to a log file and it doesn't contain the execution number

Comment: Oh, are we talking about a test class? Then you need to add the system property to the surefire plugin. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sean. I got it working finally by adding -DEXECUTOR_NUMBER=${EXECUTOR_NUMBER} in the main project's pom file in maven-osgi-test-plugin, configuration, argLine, then adding EXECUTOR_NUMBER=${EXECUTOR_NUMBER} in Hudson's job configuration, build, properties section. I don't have a maven-surefire-plugin for some reason.

Comment: @PhilJ didn't know about that plugin, but the concept is the same :-)